# How to replace <a> tag with Link components in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Our application uses a lot of pre-cooked HTML for certain pages; since these are not standard React components they cannot utilise Next.js Link component or Routing. Due to this, we cannot use Next.js to its fullest extent.
We need to find a way to replace regular hyperlink tags "" with Link components before the HTML is inserted into the page or React components. This has to be done on the server-side as well as on the client-side.
I need to find a mechanism that allows hyperlinks in pre-cooked HTML to be handled by Next.js' Routing.

Comment: Are you copy pasting the html into react, or is the html coming in as string data?

Comment: This html is coming as string data populated by a CMS.

Comment: Then I think the answer is to search the string for a tags and add onClick attribute on them that progrematically navigates, with one of the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/1704733